# Python How to create an else if statement within a dataframe that is dependant on another column

Tags: python, jupyter

e.g. I have created a data frame.  There is a heading for years.  I want to populate it with random values for each year (within a certain limit). If the year is 2001 then the values should be randomly selected from 15000 to 20000.  If the year is 2010 then the values can be from 5000 to 7000.

I have `df ['mileage'] = np.random.randint(0,20000,100)` and that returns different values for the `df` but some values for 2001 have less than 2010.  I would like to change it so that 2001 would have more than 2010.

The years have been randomly generated also.  It looks like this:

```
year    fuel  mileage      status     sex licence_type

2006  diesel    19184        fail    male         full

2007  diesel     9186        fail  female         full
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? For example, a smaller version of your Pandas DataFrame or NumPy array (possibly with random values)?

Comment: Can you explain how to get the range given the years?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```py
is_2001 = df['year'] == 2001
lower_bound = is_2001*15000 + ~is_2001*5000
upper_bound = is_2001*20000 + ~is_2001*7000
df['mileage'] = np.random.randint(lower_bound, upper_bound)
```